# How to make Input form only numbers

Tags: html, css, reactjs, validation, input

I'm making input that user could only type number or float number. If I type text it clears out whole input.I want forbid type text without clearing field . Any ideas how to make it?

```
<input
   type="text"
   id="willBeCreditedAmount"
   maxLength={9}
   placeholder="Enter amount"
   pattern="[0-9]*"
   onChange={(e) => this.props.updateWillBeCreditedAmount(e.target.value, currentComProfile)
   }
   value={willBeCreditedAmount}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="number"/>
```